# how to download files from cache directory to Android download directory

Tags: flutter, dart, storage

I download files from FTP and store them in `cache` directory using `path_provider` package

```
Future<void> _fileMock(String strFileName) async {
    try {
      final Directory appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory()..createSync(recursive: true);
      String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
      print('appDocPath : $appDocPath');
      _file = File('$appDocPath/$strFileName');
      setSavePath('$appDocPath/$strFileName');
      print('file : $file');
    }catch(e){
      print('_fileMock Error : ${e.toString()}');

      final File file = File('');
    }
  }
```

The path to the `cache` directory is `/data/user/0/package name/cache/fileName`
The file will download normally.

I want to copy or download files from the `cache` directory to the download directory. Attach an image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Solved***
Implement in JAVA and call with MethodChannel.

```
///JAVA
Map<String, String> arg = call.arguments();

            String strPath = arg.get("path");
            String strFileName = arg.get("fileName");

            assert strPath != null;
            File fP02 = new File(strPath);
            File file;

            try {
            assert strFileName != null;
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), strFileName);
                Files.copy(fP02.toPath(), file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                result.success(file.getPath());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```